# Redirect 301 on a HTML page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm stuck with this simple issue. I have a bunch of HTML pages, which have been moved in a sub-folder. Therefore, google has false adresses indexed. I would like to create à redirection (301 - moved permanently), but only .HTML pages are involved and I can't use PHP for this reason.

Do you have any solution ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? This should be pretty straightforward with rewrites.

Comment: .htaccess rule to do that for all .html

Comment: What Server-OS / configuration are you using?

Comment: htaccess url redirection?

Comment: Oh great !! Thx a lot :) ! I will try the .htaccess method.